# Angularjs huge application ng-boilerplate laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ngboilerplate

Im building a HUGE application in angularjs and laravel with around 500 tables and dynamic role security. I want to use ng-boilerplate but it compiles all my js and views into a single file. Will that file be too big for the initial load? It seems to me like an overkill. Do you have any suggestion to load only relevent modules?

Comment: Im trying to integrate laravel with ng-boilerplate, can you share how you solved the issue of "vendor" directory for both projects?

Comment: we create a folder "api_foo" for laravel with hostname api.foo.com and our main site folder is "foo" with hostname foo.com. So, our main site is using the api.

Comment: Hi, thanks, are you using grunt serve and proxy configuration for a different port backend api ? Would be valid to setup one apache vhost for backend, another for frontend, and use Access-Control-Allow-Origin for backend to allow cross origin requests from frontend?

Comment: it's a little late but take a look at https://github.com/whisher/lama